# Create PatientID in R

Tags: r

I need to generate 13 digits PatientID using first 3 letters of the first name, last two letters of the last name, number of letters in the last name (up to 9), gender (F or M) and date of birth in the MMDDYY format. 
Here is my Practice Data Set
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyYp0.png)

I use the following code, but it does not work

```
> PracticeData$PatientID<- paste0(str_sub(PracticeData$FIRST,1,3),
+ str_sub(PracticeData$LAST,-2),
+ str_length(PracticeData$LAST),
+ PracticeData$BIRTHDAY,
+ PracticeData$GENDER))
```

The PatientID does not consist the string that I need
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30RMk.png)

Again, the code does not include the birthday in MMDDYY form, the length of the last name is not limited to 9 and gender should appear as F or M. Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: Please try to not post images of your data. You can use `dput(your_data)` to get the structure of your data and then post that in the question. Doing that makes it easy for others to reproduce your data and work on the problem.

Comment: Is this just an exercise or a real dataset? If the latter: patients with such IDs would be easily identifiable, which is probably undesirable. And there's little point in creating an ID string from which to parse information when that information is available already in the variables.

Comment: It is an exercise

Answer (score 3):

Some information is missing, however assuming that you are able to read the data into a data frame, the following might help with your answer:

```
FIRST = c("Barabara", "Filip", "Lupe", "Mariola")
LAST = c("Lee", "Rice", "De","Valhenstadt")
BIRTHDAY = c("1986-01-01", "1989-04-08", "1976-02-10","1969-11-19")
BIRTHDAY = as.Date(BIRTHDAY)
GENDER = c("Female","Male","Female","FEMALE")

PracticeData = data.frame(FIRST, LAST, BIRTHDAY, GENDER)

PracticeData$PatientID = paste0(str_sub(PracticeData$FIRST,1,3),
    str_sub(PracticeData$LAST,-2),
    ifelse(str_length(PracticeData$LAST) <=9, str_length(PracticeData$LAST), 9),
    PracticeData$BIRTHDAY,
    str_sub(PracticeData$GENDER,1,1))

PracticeData$PatientID = gsub("-", "", PracticeData$PatientID)

> PracticeData$PatientID
[1] "Baree319860101F" "Filce419890408M" "LupDe219760210F" "Mardt919691119F"
```

The **ifelse()** condition in the code will make last names longer than 9 letters to be recorded as 9 letters. The last name "Valhenstadt" in the example above is 11 characters long but it is recorded in the Parient ID "Mardt919691119F" as 9.

Comment: Everything looks great, but how to limit the count of the letters in the last name to 9, so that if the last name contains 10 letters it will be recorded as 9.

Comment: Post edited to manage this condition. _ifelse_ condition was included.

Comment: @Kevin : hi, was the edited answer able to fix everything and solve your problem?